# How can I make an object switch colors without using an animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have created a roof object for my mouse, and I want to change the color in game without using any animations. How can I achieve this through code? If anyone could point me into the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Hoping to constantly change colors every few seconds.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the component from the Renderer and change the material color! If you want to change the color every certain amount of time you can use coroutines.